# How to Set OnClickListener to Card in PlaceholderView?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am using [PlaceHolderView](https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView) library to show an Infinite List of contents like the Facebook Android app. I was using InfinitePlaceHolderView for it. It looks like this:[image]

And here is how it looks like [output](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c39ca0dfb2abd20896f761ba7b1899085b8a7568/68747470733a2f2f6a616e69736861722e6769746875622e696f2f676966732f696e66696e6974655f7669642e676966)

Now If the story is large then a user can click on the card view and it will take him to a new activity where there will be a detail of that story. For this, I need to add a Listener. But I could not find any documentation at all, how to implement it. The documentation shows that all those cards are dynamically created and not any of those cards have any id so that I can put a listener.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did is given below:

In my `feed.xml` file which contain the above view, I set an `id` for the whole view. Then I used that `id` and used it `ItemView.java` from [here](https://medium.com/@janishar.ali/android-infinite-list-with-load-more-example-3749ea7bc33):

`feed.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.example.shamsad.tutionhub.activities.FeedActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/tbHome"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/grey_100">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.mindorks.placeholderview.InfinitePlaceHolderView
        android:id="@+id/loadMoreView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

`ItemView.java`

```
@Click(R.id.rootView)
    public void onCardClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", mInfo.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("caption", mInfo.getCaption());
        intent.putExtra("salary", mInfo.getSalary());
        intent.putExtra("routine", mInfo.getRoutine());
        intent.putExtra("time", mInfo.getTime());
        Log.d("sajid", "onClick");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So, in this `onCardClick()` method, the clickable id is set up by this code `@Click(R.id.rootView)`. And that's all. It basically sets the whole `card-view` as a clickable thing.

And also thanks to the writer of this great library **Janisher Ali**. I contacted him and he helped a lot, and it worked.

[This](https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView) is a great library. To me much better than `RecyclerView`. You can try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

In step three of the documentation you have an example of the Event Bind:

```
@Animate(Animation.ENTER_LEFT_DESC)
@NonReusable
@Layout(R.layout.gallery_item_big)
public class ImageTypeBig {

    @View(R.id.imageView)
    private ImageView imageView;

    private String mUrl;
    private Context mContext;
    private PlaceHolderView mPlaceHolderView;

    public ImageTypeBig(Context context, PlaceHolderView placeHolderView, String url) {
        mContext = context;
        mPlaceHolderView = placeHolderView;
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Resolve
    private void onResolved() {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mUrl).into(imageView);
    }

    @LongClick(R.id.imageView)
    private void onLongClick(){
        mPlaceHolderView.removeView(this);
    }

}
```

More information:
https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView#step-3-create-item-class-to-bind-and-define-view-operations

Comment: It actually works for only the imageview as the imageview is larger there. Whereas in my case I want to set the listener for the whole card.

Comment: Try to set your component clickable/toutchable and make sure you have no components inside the card consuming the event.